# BigQuery - can a project be created using the API?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-bigquery-java

I'm using `com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery` and the `projects()` method only has `list()`:

`bigquery.projects().list();`.

How to create a project using the API?

Comment: Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#api) help you?

Comment: @kiranmathew: thanks, but unfortunately I need to do it from within java. Not sure what SDK they're referring to with the `projects()` call.

Comment: Hi @Buffalo ,According to the google cloud documentation [bigquery project](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects) has only two methods list and getServiceAccount. The create method is available in [resource-manager](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects) `cloudResourceManager.projects().create()`.Let me know if the create method in the resource-manager addresses your requirement or not.<br>

Comment: hi @kiranmathew, I am reluctant to try and add another API as I would probably have authentication issues with that one too. For the moment I concluded that the API I was using (google api services bigquery) can't create projects, but it can create Datasets and Tables.

I think this one can: google cloud bigquery, but I could not figure out how to use authentication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76530350/bigquery-accessing-data-with-oauth-credentials