# BigQuery - accessing data with OAuth credentials

Tags: google-bigquery, google-bigquery-java

How can I interact with Bigquery using OAuth credentials (refresh tokens)?

I've managed to do it using classes from the `com.google.api.services.bigquery` package:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Datasets;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Tabledata.InsertAll;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.DatasetList;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.QueryRequest;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.QueryResponse;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableCell;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableDataInsertAllRequest;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableDataInsertAllResponse;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableId;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
        .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
        .setClientSecrets("clientId", "clientSecret")
        .build()
        .setFromTokenResponse(new TokenResponse().setRefreshToken("refreshToken"));

    credential.refreshToken();
    Bigquery bigquery = new Bigquery.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName("xxx").build();

    Datasets.List datasetRequest = aBigquery.datasets().list("projectId");
    DatasetList datasetList = datasetRequest.execute();
    if (datasetList.getDatasets() != null)
    {
      List<DatasetList.Datasets> datasets = datasetList.getDatasets();
      System.out.println("Available datasets\n----------------");
      for (com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.DatasetList.Datasets dataset : datasets)
      {
        System.out.format("%s\n", dataset.getDatasetReference().getDatasetId());
      }
    }
}
```

But not using google's samples, which use classes from the `com.google.cloud.bigquery` package.

So my question would be: how to specify a refresh token in [this snippet](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/listing-datasets)?

```
import com.google.api.gax.paging.Page;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery.DatasetListOption;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Dataset;

public class ListDatasets {

  public static void runListDatasets() {
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    String projectId = "MY_PROJECT_ID";
    listDatasets(projectId);
  }

  public static void listDatasets(String projectId) {
    try {
      // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
      // once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
      BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

      Page<Dataset> datasets = bigquery.listDatasets(projectId, DatasetListOption.pageSize(100));
      if (datasets == null) {
        System.out.println("Dataset does not contain any models");
        return;
      }
      datasets
          .iterateAll()
          .forEach(
              dataset -> System.out.printf("Success! Dataset ID: %s ", dataset.getDatasetId()));
    } catch (BigQueryException e) {
      System.out.println("Project does not contain any datasets \n" + e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```